# Trying to send HTTP response message over TCP in Python

Tags: python, html, http, sockets, server

I made a server in python and am trying to send a http message containing contents of an html page but the full content of my website will not send. It cuts off the last body and html tags everytime. I am not sure why

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

import thread
import sys
from socket import*
from urlparse import urlparse
from datetime import datetime
import os
import select
import signal




def assignsocket():
    i=1;
    p=1;
    q=0;
    num_ports=int((len(sys.argv)-1))
    port=[]
    sockets=[]
    while q<num_ports:
        port.append(int(sys.argv[p]))
        print(int(sys.argv[p]))
        p=p+1
        serverSocket= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        serverSocket.bind(("",port[q]))
        sockets.append(serverSocket)
        q=q+1
        serverSocket.listen(1)
        print('The server is ready to recieve')
    return sockets
    
def connectandsend(socketlist):
    while True:
        readable, writable, exceptional=select.select(socketlist, [], [])
        def keyboardinterrupt(signal, frame):
            exit(0)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, keyboardinterrupt)
        for t in readable:
            connectionSocket, addr= t.accept()
            sentence= connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
        def pagedisplay(connectionSocket):
            g=""
            httpmessage=open("mfile.py", "w")
            httpmessage.write(sentence)
            httpmessage.close()
            httpmessage=open("mfile.py", "r")
            getline=str(httpmessage.readline())
            hostline=str(httpmessage.readline())
            i=4
            j=6
            path=""
            netloc=""
            while getline[i]!=" ":
                path=path+getline[i]
                i=i+1
            while j<len(hostline):
                netloc=netloc+hostline[j]
                j=j+1
            o=urlparse(str('http://'+netloc+path))
            hostname=o.hostname
            newhttpmessage=open("nfile.py", "w")
            newhttpmessage.write(str("GET "+ path + " HTTP/1.1 \n"))
            newhttpmessage.write(str("Host: "+hostname+" \n"))
            a=1
            while a<8:
                newhttpmessage.write(str(httpmessage.readline()))
                a=a+1
        
            httpmessage.close()
            newhttpmessage.close()
            newhttpmessage=open("nfile.py", "r")
            newsentence=newhttpmessage.read().splitlines()
            b=0
            finalmessage=""
            while b<9:
                finalmessage=finalmessage+str(newsentence[b])+" \n"
                b=b+1
            print(finalmessage)
            if finalmessage.find("Connection: keep-alive")!=-1:
                connection="keep-alive"
            else:
                connection="close"
            e=1
            content=""
            while e<(len(path)):
                content=content+str(path[e])
                e=e+1
            try:
                data=open(str(content), "r")
                size=os.path.getsize(str(content))
                size1=str(size)
            except IOError:
                print("file not found")
                connectionSocket.close()
                g="no"

            if g!="no":
                print("yes")
                data1=data.read().splitlines()  
                c=0
                response=""
                date=datetime.now()
                year=date.strftime("%Y")
                month=date.strftime("%m")
                day=date.strftime("%d")
                dayname=date.strftime("%a")
                time=date.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                date_time=date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
                while c<len(data1):
                    response=response+str(data1[c])+" \n"
                    c=c+1
                responsemessage=("HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\n"
                "Connection: "+ connection + "  \r\n"
                "Date: "+ dayname + ", " + date_time + " GMT \r\n"
                "Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)\r\n"
                "Last-Modified:  " + dayname + ", " +  date_time+ " GMT \r\n"
                "Content-Length: "+ size1+ " \r\n"
                "Content-Type: text/html \r\n"
                + "\r\n" + response + "\r\n\r\n")

                print(responsemessage)
                connectionSocket.send(responsemessage)
                loop=""
                if responsemessage.find("Connection: close")==-1:
                    loop="going"
                else:
                    connectionSocket.close()
    
    
        try:
            thread.start_new_thread(pagedisplay(connectionSocket))
            thread.start_new_thread(pagedisplay(connectionSocket))
        except:
            print("Error: unable to start thread")


def main():
    socketlist=[]
    socketlist=assignsocket()
    connectandsend(socketlist)

main()
```

this is primarily the code im concerned with

```
while c<len(data1):
                        response=response+str(data1[c])+" \n"
                        c=c+1
                    responsemessage=("HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\n"
                    "Connection: "+ connection + "  \r\n"
                    "Date: "+ dayname + ", " + date_time + " GMT \r\n"
                    "Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)\r\n"
                    "Last-Modified:  " + dayname + ", " +  date_time+ " GMT \r\n"
                    "Content-Length: "+ size1+ " \r\n"
                    "Content-Type: text/html \r\n"
                    + "\r\n" + response + "\r\n\r\n")
    
                    print(responsemessage)
                    connectionSocket.send(responsemessage)
```

my response message when I print it out shows the full message but when sent to the browser, it always cuts off towards the end

Comment: Why do you use `\r\n` just use `\n`. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/

Comment: thank you, i tried this however the problem still exists

Comment: @BemwaMalak: the HTTP standard specifically requires `\r\n` and not only `\n`.

Comment: @JayHarris: You are assuming that `send` will send all data. This assumptions is false. You either need to check the return code of `send` to what was actually send and do more `send` calls for the rest - or simply use `sendall`.